# How to detect all error_log files anywhere on a shared hosting?

Tags: php, error-log

Shared hosting on Appache server
I have many addon and subdomains
And want to detect all "error_log" files, anywhere
Can I do that using php or any other way ?

Of course, I can manually create an array of paths and then check them, but I hope that php can recognize them

Something like this:

```
foreach($main_domain_and_addon_and_sub as $path){
  $path = $path . '/' . 'error_log';
  if(is_file($path)){
    $story = file_get_contents($path);
    echo $story;
  }
}
```